percent stacked bar chart not scaling to 100%
It's clear I'm not understanding the math behind what I wish to accomplish.  I want a stacked bar chart showing the percent contribution of each contamination source to the total ASV counts per sample.  My example data trytry (dput() below) contains simplified information including the sample name ($name), ASV genus ($Genus), the control the ASV originated from ($cont), and the relative ASV abundance ($contmeanabund) calculated using decostand(x, method="total") on the original ASV count matrix.  The column $perc2 was calculated with the code below, and $perc are these values from the whole dataset.
sum <- sum(as.numeric(trytry$contmeanabund))
trytry$perc2 <- (as.numeric(trytry$contmeanabund) / sum) * 100

When I visualize trytry I am hoping to see full bars (to 100%) for each sample including 3H2C where all of that sample would be blue, or shipcontrolsea. Instead I see bars that reflect the relative abundance of the total counts.
 ugh <- ggplot(trytry, aes(x=name,y=perc2,fill=cont)) +
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) 
    print(ugh)

Any thoughts?
 dput(trytry)
structure(list(name = c("3H1C", "3H1C", "3H2C", "3H2C", "2H5C", 
"3H1C", "3H1C"), Genus = c("SAR116_clade", "SAR116_clade", "SAR116_clade", 
"SAR116_clade", "Nitrosopumilaceae", "Nitrosopumilaceae", "Nonlabens"
), cont = c("shipcontrolsea", "shipcontrolsea", "shipcontrolsea", 
"shipcontrolsea", "shipcontrolcore", "shipcontrolcore", "shipcontrolsea"
), perc = c(0.00166599678693457, 0.00166599678693457, 0.000187516304444513, 
0.000187516304444513, 0.00929045574925936, 0.0042522379814814, 
0.00166599678693457), contmeanabund = c(0.00268791084381583, 
0.00268791084381583, 0.000302537863254877, 0.000302537863254877, 
0.0149891746180217, 0.00686053939031891, 0.00268791084381583), 
    perc2 = c(8.80747377072101, 8.80747377072101, 0.991325401062996, 
    0.991325401062996, 49.1150078867825, 22.4799199989284, 8.80747377072101
    )), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(name = c("2H5C", 
"3H1C", "3H1C", "3H2C"), cont = c("shipcontrolcore", "shipcontrolcore", 
"shipcontrolsea", "shipcontrolsea"), .rows = structure(list(5L, 
    6L, c(1L, 2L, 7L), 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))


Just change to position="fill". What you have now gives you the right bars lengths, they add up to 100%.

You beautiful, beautiful person.

It sounds like you want to show share within each name, which you could calculate manually like this: ggplot(trytry |> ungroup() |> mutate(share_name = contmeanabund / sum(contmeanabund), .by = name),   aes(x=name,y=share_name,fill=cont)) + ...
